# Access denied on DigitalOcean root user

Tags: ubuntu, hosting, cloud-hosting, digital-ocean, ubuntu-14.04

I got my first Droplet with a LAMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04.
When I try to access mysql, I get a access denied error.

[image: Access denied error]

How is this possible when I login with the root user?

Answer (score 0):

To login to MySQL as root, use:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

You can also optionally provide the password as part of the command. If you don't, you'll be asked for the password interactively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login with the root password. The password for Digital Ocean instances can be found in the "message of the day" i.e. the message that appears when you login to a linux instance.